# How do I open the chest on the southeast corner of Tikarel Island?

Tags: oceanhorn

I am confounded by how I am supposed to reach this chest. I managed to spawn it by hitting the (cleverly hidden off screen) archery target, but it landed on a spot that I cannot reach, as I am unable to climb this small half step ledge shown in the picture because video game logic. I am also unable to open it from an oblique angle, and pushing the crate is not getting me anywhere.

[image: MYSTERY BOX]

How do I acquire the contents of this box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go just on the cliff above, there is a crate (the same crate you pushed next to the chest I guess).
Push the crate and make it fall, then jump on top of it.
No need to touch the crate more, just leave it.
A mere last jump will do the trick.

Comment: ... Jump? I can *JUMP?!*

Comment: This is the correct answer @LessPop_MoreFizz You'll get a boot item later in the game that allows you to jump small gaps. The crate pushed off the cliff allows you to fall down onto the half step on the upper/left side, and the boots allow you to hop over to the half step where the chest is.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the boots to get this. From the top cliff, push the box back toward the well, then off the cliff. It's hard to describe, so below is a diagram of the smaller cliff below. The O's are the bits of land on the smaller cliff, and the X is your target.

_ __  O O

O X O O

You want to put the box in the space where you can push it from the left over to the bigger open spot. If you push the box down and then to the far right (so it lights up with the chest), you can actually walk through the two rocks that look like they block you. The chest gets you a chunk of XP.